# Query working in MySQL Workbench but getting SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'days_applicable' in 'field list' in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this table:
[Main Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQrIq.png)

And my intended query output, which I am getting is:
[Query Output Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3nUC.png)

Now I achieved my desired output & it is working in any MySQL client like Workbench & PHPMyAdmin but it is not working in Laravel Application. No matter how many different ways I tried to solve this problem but the issue persist.

###### Error which I am getting:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
'days_applicable' in  'field list' (SQL: select MIN(id), ShowId,
ShowName, SeasonId,
GROUP_CONCAT(days_applicable ORDER BY id) as days_applicable from
TvShowList group by ShowId, ShowName, SeasonId)
```

###### My MySQL Query in plain version:

```
SELECT MIN(id),ShowId,ShowName, SeasonId, GROUP_CONCAT(days_applicable ORDER BY id) as days_applicable 
FROM TvShowList GROUP BY ShowId,ShowName, SeasonId;
```

###### Laravel Query Builder Query:

```
DB::table('TvShowList')
->select(DB::raw('MIN(id)'),'ShowId','ShowName','SeasonId',
DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(days_applicable ORDER BY id) as days_applicable'))                                    
->groupBy('ShowId','ShowName','SeasonId')                                    
->get();
```

###### On using toSql to get the genrated SQL is same as expected:

```
SELECT MIN(id),ShowId,ShowName, SeasonId, GROUP_CONCAT(days_applicable ORDER BY id) as days_applicable 
    FROM TvShowList GROUP BY ShowId,ShowName, SeasonId;
```

There are other variations also like using subquery, inline query, inner joins but it didn't solve the problem. **Note that before posting here I did search other similar problems in SO but unlike in those cases**:

1. I do have the mentioned column within the mentioned table.
2. The spelling is proper & so is casing.
3. Even if a consider the case of a missing column or if I am in wrong table or vice versa cases, then how can it work at MySQL client & not in Laravel app. I copy pasted the working code into Laravel's DB::select, DB::raw, DB::statement but it still gave me the same error.
4. I am not using any migration code here.
5. I checked the connection of the MySQL client & the Laravel application, it is the same.
6. I have even tried changing the alias to something else.

###### Below is my Model code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Beforetv extends Model
{
    //

    protected $connection = 'beforetv';

    protected $table = 'TvShowList';

    protected $fillable = ['ShowId','ShowName','SeasonId','days_applicable'];

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

###### Here's my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Beforetv;
use App\Http\Requests\BeforetvRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class BeforetvController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
            $data['beforetv_list'] = DB::table('TvShowList')
                                    ->select(DB::raw('MIN(id)'),'ShowId','ShowName','SeasonId','ShowStartTime','ShowEndTime','STATUS',DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(days_applicable ORDER BY id) as days_applicable'))
                                    ->groupBy('ShowId','ShowName','SeasonId','ShowStartTime','ShowEndTime','STATUS')                                    
                                    ->get();
            

        }
        $data['p_0'] = false;
        $data['auth_access_level'] = auth()->user()->access_level;
        return view('beforetv.index', $data);
    }
 }
```

###### Latest Edit Update:

I did 'select * all' in

query builder i.e. DB::table('TvShowList')->get();

&

eloquent i.e. Beforetv::all();

as well & it turns out that in eloquent it is showing the so called missing column but in query builder it is not showing. So what could be the cause of this strange issue?

So can anyone please help me in finding out where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Can change as days applicable to another name. Is beforetv connection is the same with mysql one? And did you try to clear your cache?

Comment: @gguney: Yes as said in description, connection, spelling & casing is same for both.... & i have tried changing alias but it persists

Comment: have you tried adding an alias (TvShowList ) to the fields name in query ?

Comment: @LiudmilaSavateeva: I didn't get you. You mean to say using an alias to the mentioned table. If that's the case then I have already tried it & it isn't working & there's no other table for the system to be confused.

Comment: To make sure you have the right table, change the name of days_applicable to DaysAapplicable and run your querys again with the new name. This way the name is also within the camelcase youre using

Answer (score 0):

Any change if you do

```
->select(DB::raw("MIN(id),ShowId,ShowName,SeasonId,
GROUP_CONCAT(days_applicable ORDER BY id) as days_applicable"))...
```

Comment: I have tried that its the same issue but I found something while debugging. I did query builder i.e. DB::table('TvShowList')->get();

&

eloquent i.e. Beforetv::all();

Comment: it turns out that in eloquent it is showing the so called missing column but in query builder it is not showing. what could be the cause of this strange issue?